# Sun HTTPServer - how can I write post-process filter?

Tags: java, com.sun.net.httpserver

I trying some things with the HTTP server of Sun JRE. After reading twice the documentation, I am still confused.

The [com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/Filter.html) javadoc says the following

> Asks this filter to pre/post-process the given exchange. The filter can :
>
> - examine or modify the request headers
> - filter the request body or the response body, by creating suitable filter streams and calling HttpExchange.setStreams(InputStream,OutputStream)
> - set attribute Objects in the exchange, which other filters or the exchange handler can access.
> - decide to either :
>
>   - invoke the next filter in the chain, by calling Filter.Chain.doFilter(HttpExchange)
>   - terminate the chain of invocation, by not calling Filter.Chain.doFilter(HttpExchange)
>
>   if option 1. above taken, then when doFilter() returns all subsequent filters in the Chain have been called, and the response headers can be examined or modified.
>     if option 2. above taken, then this Filter must use the HttpExchange to send back an appropriate response

What does not clear for me, what decides when the filter is pre- or post-process filter.
As I assume, post-process filter is runs *after* the HttpHandler, so it can work with HttpExchange what is modified by HttpHandler. However, filter is called only once, so there must be a "magic" what decides the filter runs before or after the handler.

Please help me to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've wondered about this myself and I don't see how the `setStreams` method can be helpful for this. The only way I could do this is by wrapping HttpExchange.

This example shows how to apply gzip compression with a Filter:

https://gist.github.com/Crydust/7e4e9228cd95febccdc58f0501c1e327

Answer (score 3):

Every filter is both a pre and post filter. What I mean by that is the Request passes through it as it moves through the stack, and then the Response comes back through it on the way out to the client. The order that the filter is called depends on the order you mount it in your `web.xml` file.

If you were using it as a Pre filter, you would modify the `InputStream` and if you wanted it as a Post you would modify the `OutputStream`. You can even pass your own `InputStream` and `OutputStream` down through the chain.

So, say for example you had a few `Filter1`, `Filter2` and `Filter3`. The `InputStream` would first go through `Filter1`, then `Filter2` and finally `Filter3` before being processed. The resulting `OutputStream` would then go back through `Filter3`, then `Filter2` and finally `Filter1` before being sent to the client. So, in that way you can modify pre and/or post processing.

Comment: Sorry, `web.xml` is part of the JEE spec. I realize you mentioned the Sun HTTP server, which I believe is configured through code - however the filter stack is still chained together, so you still filter pre or post based on which stream you modify.

Comment: I just forgot this topic. I figured out this is implemented in different way as I imagined. If I have a time enough I will add some docs here about how this stuff working

Answer (score 1):

*Filter.doFilter()* is called **only once, before** *HttpHandler.handle()* is called.

This means that you cannot modify the content of the HTTP response after your handler has run. So, it's more naturally a pre-filter.

However, in your implementation of *doFilter()*, you can wrap the the response's *OutputStream* with your own *FilterOutputStream*, so you can intercept the calls to *HttpExchange.getResponseBody().write(...)*.

```java
class MyFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(HttpExchange exch, Chain chain) throws IOException {

        exch.setStreams(null, new MyInterceptedOutputStream(exch.getResponseBody()));
        chain.doFilter(exch);
    }

    ...
}
```

This *MyInterceptedOutputStream* class will need to extend *OutputStream* and implement its usual methods (*write()* and *close()*)

One trick: Your wrapper must ensure that it will not write anything to the original *OutputStream* until *HttpExchange.sendResponseHeaders()* has been called. This means that you have to make sure that your wrapper constructor (*MyInterceptedOutputStream(OutputStream os)* in the above example) doesn't not write anything, unlike *GZIPOutputStream()* for example!

Bonus: Example of an *OutputStream* wrapper that compresses the stream... and works in *HttpFilter.doFilter()*

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;

public class GZIPDelayedOutputStream extends OutputStream {

    GZIPOutputStream gzipStream;
    OutputStream originalStream;

    public GZIPDelayedOutputStream(OutputStream os) {
        super();
        originalStream = os;
    }

    private void createGzipStreamIfNecessary() throws IOException {
        if (gzipStream == null) {
            gzipStream = new GZIPOutputStream(originalStream);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        createGzipStreamIfNecessary();
        gzipStream.write(b);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte buf[]) throws IOException {
        createGzipStreamIfNecessary();
        gzipStream.write(buf);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] buf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        createGzipStreamIfNecessary();
        gzipStream.write(buf, off, len);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        createGzipStreamIfNecessary();
        gzipStream.close();
    }
}
```